# i don't know how to fix this error, python3 syntax error 'def'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, syntax-error

I want to solve this error.
i tried for almost half hours, but I couldn't find the answer..

This is my error

```
 File "sampling_fun.py", line 71
    def average(self) :
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and full code

```
import csv

class fun :
    def __init__(self, rowList, num) :
        list = []
        listLen = len(self.rowlist)-1
        for i in range(listLen) :
            list.append(self.rowList[i+1][num]  # num = Header 1~4

    def average(self) :
        ave = sum(self.list)/self.lestLen
        print("average : %0.2f" %ave)
        return ave

testlist = cssRead('Data_2', 1)
test1 = fun(testlist, 1)
test1.average()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you encounter such error, check the line before it.

You have a non-matching paranthesis, the closing brace for append is missing.

```
list.append(self.rowList[i+1][num])
```

Comment: ohh thx, it was a silly mistake....

Answer (score 1):

`def` errors happen when python is not expecting a function definition. As @Siong Thye Goh notes, a missing `)` is your issue. For the future, the only time python does not expect a function definition is after an incomplete code-block.

That can happen when you forget to close parentheses or brackets, but also when you forget to put a statement after a colon or don't indent correctly.

Rarely, it can happen due to incompatible space characters when copy-pasting from external sources.